# I want to find complexs roots in Python but I can't do 'else' part

Tags: python

```
import math
```

while True:

```
a = int(input("enter the number a:"))
if a == 0:
    print("Cannot be 0!")
    continue
b = int(input("enter the number b:"))
c = int(input("enter the number c:"))
print(f"Equation:{a}x^2+{b}x+{c}")
discriminant = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
rootdiscriminant=discriminant**0.5
if discriminant > 0:
    root1 = ((-b) + math.sqrt(discriminant)) / 2 * a
    root2 = ((-b) - math.sqrt(discriminant)) / 2 * a
    print(root1,root2)
elif discriminant == 0:
    root = (-b)/2*a
    print(root)
```

/* I have a trouble in this part */
else:
t=(-b)//2*a
k=rootdiscriminant/2
print(t,"+",complex(k))
print(t, "-", complex(k))

```
break
```

Answer (score 0):

The only real problem with your answer is that

1. you need to surround `2*a` with parentheses, like `(2*a)`.
2. you used floor division (`//`) in the `else` block, where you need to use real division

```py
a,b,c = [None]*3
while True:
    a,b,c = map(int, input("Enter a, b, and c separated by spaces: ").split())
    if a == 0:
        print("`a` cannot be 0!")
        continue
    break

print(f"Equation:{a}x^2+{b}x+{c}")

discriminant = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
rootdiscriminant = discriminant**0.5
if discriminant > 0:
    root1 = (-b + rootdiscriminant) / (2 * a)
    root2 = (-b - rootdiscriminant) / (2 * a)
    print(root1,root2)
elif discriminant == 0:
    root = (-b)/(2*a)
    print(root)
else:
    t=(-b)/(2*a)
    k=rootdiscriminant/(2*a)
    print(t+k)
    print(t-k)
```